# How do I change the contents of the command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

How can I permanently change the contents of the command prompt under Windows 7? I know about the `prompt` command, and the [content options](http://www.computerhope.com/prompthl.htm#03), but I'm not sure where to save the custom prompt so that it's used every time. Old web pages say `autoexec.bat`, but that seems to be an uneditable dummy file under 7.

Comment: I know it is an old question, but yet still valid in nearly 2021... and wow... `autoexec.bat` brings back memories from the 80s and 90s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the User Environment variables.

Right Click Computer --> Properties --> Advanced Settings --> Advanced --> Environment Variables

In the User variables box click "New..".

Name the variable "Prompt" (without quotes), and set it's value to what you want the prompt to be (refer to "prompt /?" at a command line).

OK --> OK

Open a command prompt (cmd) and it should use that prompt.

Tested in Windows 7, and it still works like it did in NT 4 :)

Hope that helps...

Comment: and the command line way to do that `setx PROMPT $G$S`  ... change of course `$G$S` to whatever contents options you like.

Answer (score 2):

I found some instructions here: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Custom-Windows-Command-Prompt 
and here: http://windowsxp.mvps.org/autoruncmd.htm that let you customize your command prompt. 
Evidently there are several registry keys that let you modify the default behavior of cmd.