# Keeping Command Prompt Settings(Color, Title)

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

Is there a way to store settings for the command prompt, so it doesn't revert to default when you close it.

I saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/241471/how-do-i-change-the-contents-of-the-command-prompt) page which allowed me to change the prompt default but what about things like text color? Is there something similar that needs to be done?

For example I love green and dont want to do

```
color a
```

every time...

**EDIT:**

Got color, but what about Title of the window? Is there a way to make that default?

Example:

```
title My New Color Window
```

Comment: for the title there's no default configuration. You could configure a cmd.exe shortcut that executes the title command. But that's not generic enough.

Comment: you can do bpth with one command only, and put that in a shortcut. see my solution below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click the **Control Icon** in the command prompt window (icon in the top left of the window) and choose the **Defaults** options.

Tweak to your content. :)

[image]

Comment: you can click that!?!

Comment: Yup. You can. Don't worry if your changes don't show immediately. Close the window and start another 'cmd' command and those settings will show.

Comment: Or just right-click the title bar, that's exactly the same :)

Answer (score 7):

You can configure the Windows Command Prompt to run any commands you want, including `color`, `title` and `prompt` using the registry key at

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun
```

If the `Autorun` key does not exist, create a `REG_SZ` key `Autorun`.

Any commands you put in here will be executed for all new `cmd.exe` windows. Customize away!

Answer (score 3):

I have a lot of ways to change colors, but it is the easier one to change colors and title. Only "start > run" the command bellow or create a shortcut or a BAT with that command:

```
cmd /k color 89 & title=Your custom title
```