# CMD shows at start up c:\> instead of just c:\ without >?

Tags: cmd.exe

Could someone please help me?

I have a problem in Windows 7 Ultimate with the command prompt.

In fact, i am a "novice." So the all changes I try in the command line, doesn't change anything...

Whatever I do, it goes to "c:>", which is unusual, as I had ">" before?

It's C:> - or when i make changes in the registry,

It's C:\Administrator

Why do i always have ">" behind C:\ ??????

I need help - until today, I can't find a solution...

Comment: Does it matter? What output do you get from `echo %prompt%`?

Comment: Showing a > behind the path is always there. It was made the default since windows 3.11. The reason is to clearly see the seperation between the path, and where you type. Otherwise, your command could look like this: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Officeoutlook.exe` instead of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office>outlook.exe`

Comment: The default yes. Always there not necessarily.

Answer (score 3):

By default command prompt in Windows (and in DOS as far as i remember) is set to $p$g where $p stands for the current drive and path and $g stands for symbol ">" (greater than).

You can change the default prompt just by using [prompt command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/prompt) (for cmd session).

Or [permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/325213/how-can-i-permanently-customize-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7)

So if you don't want ">", you can type prompt $p$s   ($s stands for space - i believe you should have any delimiter)

But commonly the default $p$g is ok for most cases.

Comment: Yes, DOS had the `>` even before it had _folders_. I think it inherited the style from CP/M.

Comment: thank you for your answer.   Because, i am  a novice - i stil don't know waht to do..

Comment: In command line just type:
prompt $p$s 
But I don't see any reason why you should change the default prompt (especially if you are a novice).

Comment: My real problem is discribed here:    https://superuser.com/questions/1307293/command-option-to-start-sophos-anti-virus-in-safe-mode#      I can't run a sertent programm in safe mode, when i do it directly from the program - it's just starting - wihout let me any choice.  Therefore, i need to start it from the command line - but this is impossible...  not found or something like that....